# How to redirect if session not set in middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware

I am trying to redirect the user to login page if it tries to access dashboard or other user page if they haven't logged in yet.

here is my web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'UserAuthChk'], function(){
    Route::get('/',[HomeController::class, 'index']) -> name('home.index');
    // User Controller
    Route::get('/user/dashboard', [UserController::class, 'dashboard']) -> name('user.dashboard');
    
    // User Authentication Controller
    Route::get('/auth/user/login', [UserAuthController::class, 'login']) -> name('auth.user.login');
    Route::get('/auth/user/signup', [UserAuthController::class, 'signup']) -> name('auth.user.signup');
    Route::get('/auth/user/forgotpassword', [UserAuthController::class, 'forgotpass']) -> name('auth.user.forgotpass');
    // User Authentication POST
    Route::post('/auth/user/registeruser', [UserAuthController::class, 'registerUser']) -> name('auth.user.reguser');
    Route::post('/auth/user/loginuser', [UserAuthController::class, 'loginUser']) -> name('auth.user.loginuser');
    Route::get('/auth/user/logoutuser', [UserAuthController::class, 'logoutUser']) -> name('auth.user.logoutuser');
});
```

Here is my middleware UserAuthChk.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserAuthChk
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (session()->has('userID') && ($request->path()==route('auth.user.login') || $request->path()==route('auth.user.signup') || $request->path()==route('auth.user.forgotpass'))) {
            return back();
        }
        if(!session()->has('userID') && ($request->path()!=route('auth.user.login') || $request->path()!=route('auth.user.signup') || $request->path()!=route('auth.user.forgotpass') || $request->path()!=route('home.index'))) {
            return redirect()->route('auth.user.login');
        }
        
        return $next($request)->header('Cache-Control','no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate')
                              ->header('Pragma','no-cache')
                              ->header('Expires', 'Sat 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
    }
}
```

Here is my kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'UserAuthChk' => \App\Http\Middleware\UserAuthChk::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
];
```

If I haven't logged in and I try to access the login page, signup page, home page, it just keeps loading and then errors saying that it redirected too many times.

When I removed the whole `!session()` part and I loggedd in then try to access the login or signup page, it works fine. Any solutions?

Comment: why not just use the built in auth system? it handles logins and the `auth` middleware handles redirecting the user to the 'login' page if they are not authenticated

Comment: I tried that first, but it locked out the rest of the pages, e.i., about page, contact page, the download page, and other pages that doesn't need the user to be logged in.

Comment: then don't assign the `auth` middleware to those routes

Answer (score 0):

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (session()->has('userID') && ($request->path()==route('auth.user.login') || $request->path()==route('auth.user.signup') || $request->path()==route('auth.user.forgotpass'))) {
        return back();
    }
    elseif(!session()->has('userID') && ($request->path()!=route('auth.user.login') || $request->path()!=route('auth.user.signup') || $request->path()!=route('auth.user.forgotpass') || $request->path()!=route('home.index'))) {
        return redirect()->route('auth.user.login');
    }else{
return $next($request)->header('Cache-Control','no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate')
                          ->header('Pragma','no-cache')
                          ->header('Expires', 'Sat 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
    }
    
}
```